# Google Cloud Storage - Create many copies of a single object/file quickly

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to make a million copies of a single file. Right now I'm looping through and creating a copy one at a time which takes about a second per file (using bash). Is there a better/quicker way to do this?

```
for f in {1..1000000}; gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.csv "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME_${f}.csv"; done
```

Comment: You might find it is quicker to run the gsutil command using a local "FILENAME.csv" rather than copying it on GCS.  Also ... where are you running this script from?  It might be quicker to run the command on a Compute Engine already in the cloud or from a Cloud Shell.

Comment: I was originally running it in a Google Cloud Shell, but the session eventually closes for some reason after a few hundred iterations. However, since the copy operation is happening all on the cloud I don’t think the machine I’m running it on should have much of an impact (answer is i’m running on my local machine now in a background tmux session)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command to do this much faster. For example, this would create the 1 million objects, limiting to 100 instances of gsutil running at a time:

```bash
seq 1000000 | parallel --jobs 100 gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.csv \
    "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME_{}.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks! Should this work in something like Google Cloud Shell or even a basic laptop? Wondering what the bottleneck would be hardware wise (if any).

Comment: Looks like parallel warns you about how many jobs can run simultaneously: ```Warning: Only enough file handles to run 60 jobs in parallel.
```

Answer (score 1):

The way Jas wrote it is better than either of the other 2 answers because it uses copy-in-the-cloud. Both of these other answers are uploading to the cloud every time.

To do it faster you could parallelize the writes, e.g.,

```
for i in {1..10000}; do
  for j in {1..100}; do
    gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.csv "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME_${i}_${j}.csv" &
  done
  wait
done
```

You could make it faster still if you switch to (say) Python and implement using a task queue, so you keep the 100 workers continuously busy instead of spawning 100 threads and letting them each finish before spawning the next batch (as the bash implementation above does).

Comment: You have small typo here "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME_${i}_${f}.csv" : {f} instead {j}.

Answer (score -2):

I will write a nodejs program and capitalize on its asynch. It will eat a lot of cpu time though so you might need to do some batches.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const x = 1000000;
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    fs.createReadStream('./filename.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./filename'+i+'.csv'));
}
```